# Что за ошибка USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: ╧Ёшёюхфшэхээюх ъ ёшёЄхьх єёЄЁющёЄтю эх ЁрсюЄрхЄ.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Делаю парсинг сайта объявлений. Сначала собираю все ссылки на объявления с главной страницы, потом прохожусь по этим ссылкам в цикле, чтобы открывать каждую страницу и брать оттуда номер телефона.
Но возникает какая-то непонятная ошибка
[10060:8476:0927/165619.955:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [16:56:19.954] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor
from node connection: ╧Ёшёюхфшэхээюх ъ ёшёЄхьх єёЄЁющёЄтю эх ЁрсюЄрхЄ. (0x1F)

код:

```
try:
for postLink in allLinksData.values():
    driver.get(postLink["link"])
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='show-phone']"))).click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

except:
time.sleep(5)
finally:
driver.close()
driver.quit()

если из строки element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='show-phone']"))).click() убрать .click() в конце, то нормально отрабатывает - каждую страницу по ссылке открывает в браузере. Именно с click() эта ошибка